# How to manage multiple wordpress post from single dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to manage multiple wordpress posts from one dashboard ? can we create/update/delete post for two different wordpress from one  dashboard? How we can do that ? is there any plugin available related to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress provides api to retrieve posts, which can be directly displayed to another wordpress site.

You can use CURL or file_get_contents to fetch the data.